# Unable to send user input to firebase after authentication

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm trying to send user input to firebase after user authentication.I am using Ionicframework. this is what i have tried.

Error is Uncaught (in promise): Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = 'profile/${auth.uid}'.

Typescript file:

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';

/**
 * Generated class for the FpPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-fp',
  templateUrl: 'fp.html',
})
export class FpPage {

  @ViewChild('uname') uname;

  constructor(private fire:AngularFireAuth,private db :AngularFireDatabase,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  createProfile(){

this.fire.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {

this.db.list('profile/${auth.uid}').push(this.uname)
.then(() => this.navCtrl.push('TabsPage'))


})


  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad FpPage');
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-content padding>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="username" #uname></ion-input>
</ion-item>



<button ion-button clear block (click)="createProfile()">Set Username</button>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your code. You are trying to use template literals that are used with `` and allows you to use string params, but you are using common string chars ('').

To solve your code, you should change your code:

`this.db.list('profile/${auth.uid}').push(this.uname)`

to:

`` this.db.list(`profile/${auth.uid}`).push(this.uname) ``

for further documentation about template literals have a look at [MDN Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: thanks i guess that error is fixed but i had another one now :/Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains a function in property

Comment: @rektandlove As I have no access to your project, I can't debug it and it's really hard. The error says that `this.uname` has a function as a object field. That's something that @ViewChild decorator is doing for sure. Create an object with the properties you want to save at your collection:
`...push({ name: this.uname.name, otherField: this.uname.otherField })...`

Comment: @rektandlove don't forget to mark the answer as the correct answer and clarify your answer in your question if you found further errors on your code.